# Is it possible to get the full "namespace" of a struct in a custom derive?

Tags: rust

I've read [this documentation page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/procedural-macros.html) but I'm still unable to figure out how to do this.

My files are:

```
|- pancakes.rs
|- main.rs
```

I'm deriving on the struct `Pancakes` in "pancakes.rs":

```
#[derive(HelloWorld)]
struct Pancakes;
```

I have the following implementation copied from the documentation, but the `ident` does not contain the full "namespace":

```
#[proc_macro_derive(HelloWorld)]
pub fn hello_world(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let s = input.to_string();
    let ast = syn::parse_derive_input(&s).unwrap();
    let gen = impl_hello_world(&ast);
    gen.parse().unwrap()
}

fn impl_hello_world(ast: &syn::DeriveInput) -> quote::Tokens {
    let name = &ast.ident; // <---- HERE name = Pancakes, not pancakes::Pancakes
    quote! {
        impl HelloWorld for #name {
            fn hello_world() {
                println!("Hello, World! My name is {}", stringify!(#name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get all the information about the struct? I'd also like to get the cargo's lib name from where the derive is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. Custom derive work on token streams, from which you can easily build an AST. But at this level, names have not been resolved yet (which makes sense, macros and custom derives can affect how the names are resolved, so they need to be fully expended first).

Comment: Worth mentioning `$crate` though?

Comment: @Shepmaster unfortunately generating `$crate` in a procedural macro gives ``error: unknown macro variable `crate` `` and `error: proc-macro derive produced unparseable tokens`.